# How can I find maximum length interval, which is sum of open intervals? c/c++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, tree, intervals

My problem is:

You are given the array of n elements: struct Interval {int x; int y};
Elements of that array are open intervals. I have to find T intervals (or less) which sum is consistent maximum length interval.

I considered using interval tree, but have no idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you also post a sample input and output with your post, also if possible the problem link. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, the original content is not in english. For example: intervals: (0;3), (1;4), (5;7), (2;3), (9,11), (6,8) and the longest sum of intervals is (0;4). Output intervals are not the most important for me, I want to find largest interval.

Comment: Ohk basically you combine the overlapping intervals and once that's done you figure out for which interval the length is highest, this can be solved without interval tree as well, are you fine with a working solution ?

Comment: i think it can be done using stack and sorting the array by first coordinate? it would be nlogn complexity, but i have no idea how to do it in linear time (if it is possible)

Answer (score 1):

Sort (by value) all interval border points by value together with key `+1/-1` denoting start and end of intervals (in case of tie account for key value: -1 before +1 for open intervals)

Make `ActiveCount = 0`
Walk through sorted list, incrementing `ActiveCount` by key value.

When `ActiveCount` becomes non-zero, interval union starts, when it becomes zero - interval union ends. Find the longest end-start difference.

For your example (partial):

```
(0;3), (1;4), (5;7), (2;3)
make pairs 
(0, 1), (3,-1), (1, 1), (4, -1), (5,1), (7,-1), (2,1), (3,-1)
sorted 
(0, 1), (1, 1), (2,1), (3,-1), (3,-1), (4, -1), (5,1), (7,-1)
ActiveCount
 1       2       3     2        1       0        1     0
 ^                                      ^
 start                                  end
```

Comment: I dont understand. What do you mean "sort it by value together with key +-1" ? Do you mean sorting intervals (0;3), (1;4), (5;7), (2;3), (9,11), (6,8) : 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11 ?

Comment: Look at example

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen. Thank you!